# Tengo problemas de inserción de datos , por un formulario en forma de tabla

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, html5, tablas

Basandome en los resultados de esta pregunta que hice anteriormente
[Como crear botones funcionales de eliminar y agregar fila en una tabla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/382821/como-crear-botones-funcionales-de-eliminar-y-agregar-fila-en-una-tabla)
Logré crear una tabla-formulario que tenga los botones agregar y eliminar fila  , pero se presentan un problema que no he logrado solucionar : Al insertar los datos en la tabla de la base de datos, solo se insertan los datos de la primera fila de la tabla-formulario, el resto de registros no ingresan a la base de datos.

Mi formulario tiene dos partes, una es el encabezado y otra es el cuerpo, ya que es un formulario para una factura
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El encabezado esta guardado en una tabla que se
llama -tblfacturaventa - , el cuerpo de la factura esta guardado en una tabla llamada -tblfacturventaproducto-, es una tabla compuesta.
Cuando yo guarde una factura que tenga varios productos, en la base de datos deben guardarse todos los productos correspondientes a un solo numero de factura.

Aqui hay una captura de las tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta mi formulario en codigo

Este es el encabezado

```
 <form method="post" action="guardar_venta.php ">
    <input id="numero" class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="text"  name="numero">

    <select name="cliente" class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12"><?php while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_cliente)) { //array recorre datos?>
       <option value="<?php echo $datos['documento'] ?>"> <?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?></option> <?php }?>
   </select>

 <select class="col-12 form-control mr-sm-2" name="forma_pago"> <?php
while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_f_pago)) { //array recorre datos
    ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>"> <?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?></option> <?php }?>
 </select>

input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="date" name="fecha">
 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill " onclick="agregarFila()>Agregar fila</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  rounded-pill"onclick="eliminarFila()"  >  Eliminar fila</button>
```

Esta es la tabla

```
       <table class="table">

                        <thead class="table-primary">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Código</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                                <th>Precio unitario</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <!---------------------SCRIPT PARA BOTONES AGREGAR Y ELIMINAR FILA---------------->
                            <script>
                            var myTable = document.querySelector("table");

                            function agregarFila() {
                                 // No se pueden insertar más filas
                                if(myTable.rows.length >= 10) {
                                    // No se pueden insertar más filas
                                    alert('No se pueden insertar mas filas');                                    
                            
                                }
                                var row = myTable.insertRow(myTable.rows.length);
                                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                             cell1.innerHTML = `<select class="col-12 form-control mr-sm-2 " name="codigo[]" id='opciones' onchange='cambioOpciones();'>
                                <option disabled selected> - Seleccione - </option>
                                <?php
                                    while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_producto)) { //array recorre datos
                                ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>" data-nombre="<?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?>"> <?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>  </option>
                                <?php }?>
                                </select>`;
                            cell2.innerHTML ='<input type="text"  name="nombre[]"  class="form-control mr-sm-2 " >';
                            cell3.innerHTML ='<input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="number"  name="cantidad[]">';;
                            cell4.innerHTML ='<input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="number" name="precio_unitario[]">';
                                    }

                            function eliminarFila() {
                                var rowCount = myTable.rows.length;
                                if (rowCount <= 1) {
                                    alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado');
                                } else {
                                    myTable.deleteRow(rowCount - 1);
                                }

                            }

                            //  AUTOCOMPLETADO DE NOMBRE
                            function cambioOpciones(){
                                                                //el evento siempre esta disponible en la función
                                                                //event.target -> elemento que disparó el evento ( select name)
                                                                let sel = event.target;
                                                                //definir valor inicial
                                                                let value = '';
                                                                //si se selecciona una opción...
                                                                if(event.target.value){
                                                                    //tomar el nombre desde el atributo data-nombre de la opción seleccionada
                                                                    value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].dataset.nombre;
                                                                }
                                                                // Obtener fila a la que pertenece el select
                                                                let tr = sel.closest('tr');
                                                                // Obtener campo desde TR, por atributo name y asignar valor
                                                                tr.querySelector('[name="nombre[]"]').value = value;

                                                            }


                            </script>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Este es el archivo al que redirecciona el formulario(solo mostráre la parte de la inserción, considero que el resto no tiene importancia para resolver el problema)

```
include "../includes/conexion.php";
$numero = $_POST["numero"];
$cliente = $_POST["cliente"];
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$forma_pago = $_POST["forma_pago"];

// Los siguientes son arreglos, todos con la misma cantidad de elementos
$producto = $_POST["codigo"]; 
$cantidad = $_POST["cantidad"];
$precio_unitario = $_POST["precio_unitario"];

$guardar_venta = "INSERT INTO tblfacturaventa(numero,cliente,fecha,forma_pago)
VALUES ('$numero','$cliente','$fecha','$forma_pago')";


// Haces un ciclo para recorrer uno de los campos y usar el mismo índice para los otros:
foreach($producto as $index => $prod) {
    // Los elementos de arreglo deben encerrarse entre llaves
    $guardar_venta_producto = "INSERT INTO tblfacturventaproducto (factura_venta, producto, cantidad, precio_unitario)
        VALUES ('$numero', '$prod', '{$cantidad[$index]}', '{$precio_unitario[$index]}')";
    // Aquí ejecutas la consulta para insertar este producto
}

if ($conexion->query($guardar_venta) && $conexion->query($guardar_venta_producto)) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Factura Creada!");
    window.location.href="registrar_venta.php";
    </script>';

} else {    
    echo "Error: {$conexion->error}";
}
```

````

Hago una inserción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el las tablas de la base de datos se guarda esto:

tblfacturaventa
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tblfacturventaproducto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la idea es que en -tblfacturventaproducto- se guarden todos los productos relacionados con el numero de factura 7.

Comment: Saludos. No lo he trabajado así como tienes tu escenario; he leido (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407284/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-of-select-box-in-php) que usando el atributo `name` poniendo el mismo nombre pero colocando al final los corchetes (jem: ´<select name=codigo[]...>`, `<input name="nombre[]".../>`, etc) al momento que envias (según corresponda recibirlo) por `POST` o `GET` en tu php es un arreglo con cada valor. Claro (como lo muestras) existen igual numero de cada tag asi que con un `count` obten cuantos elemento son y asi con un for de 1 hasta valor de  `count`.

Comment: Intenté lo de los names[]  pero me sale error y dice que los inputs reconoce como un array,Y lo otro el count y el for, puedes explicarmelo nuevamente porfavor ?

Comment: No pusiste el código con el que ejecutas la consulta, por favor, agrega esa parte, de otra forma no podemos saber porqué solo inserta uno.

Comment: mm.. te refieres a cuando hago la inserción ?, si es eso ya lo actualizé.

Comment: No veo donde tienes algo como `$conexion->query($guardar_venta_producto);` que supongo es más o menos como lo ejecutas.

Comment: porfavor verifica otra vez el archivo a donde redirecciono el formulario, creo que ya agregé lo que me dijiste, de antemano agradezco mucho tu ayuda!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya tienes la cuenta de filas, solo necesitas comparar `myTable.rows.length` para no permitir agregar más de 10.

Luego, a todos los nombres de campo hay que agregar corchetes `[]`, para que todos sean tratados como arreglo.

```
function agregarFila() {
    if(myTable.rows.length >= 10) {
        // No se pueden insertar más filas
        // Puedes usar alert o algún otro medio para avisar al usuario
        return;
    }
    var row = myTable.insertRow(myTable.rows.length);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = `<select class="col-12 form-control mr-sm-2 " name="codigo[]" id='opciones' onchange='cambioOpciones();'>
        <option disabled selected> - Seleccione - </option>
        <?php
            while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_producto)) { //array recorre datos
        ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>" data-nombre="<?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?>"> <?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>  </option>
        <?php }?>
        </select>`;
    cell2.innerHTML ='<input type="text"  name="nombre[]"  class="form-control mr-sm-2 " >';
    cell3.innerHTML ='<input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="number"  name="cantidad[]">';;
    cell4.innerHTML ='<input class="form-control mr-sm-2 col-12" type="number" name="precio_unitario[]">';
}
```

En PHP insertas la venta y después recorres los productos para insertar cada uno en la tabla correspondiente:

```
$numero = $_POST["numero"];
$cliente = $_POST["cliente"];
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$forma_pago = $_POST["forma_pago"];

// Los siguientes son arreglos, todos con la misma cantidad de elementos
$producto = $_POST["codigo"]; 
$cantidad = $_POST["cantidad"];
$precio_unitario = $_POST["precio_unitario"];

// Esta consulta no depende del ciclo
$guardar_venta = "INSERT INTO tblfacturaventa (numero, cliente, fecha, forma_pago)
    VALUES ('$numero', '$cliente', '$fecha', '$forma_pago')";
// Aquí ejecutas la consulta para insertar la venta
$resultado_venta = $conexion->query($guardar_venta);

// Haces un ciclo para recorrer uno de los campos y usar el mismo índice para los otros:
foreach($producto as $index => $prod) {
    // Los elementos de arreglo deben encerrarse entre llaves
    $guardar_venta_producto = "INSERT INTO tblfacturventaproducto (factura_venta, producto, cantidad, precio_unitario)
        VALUES ('$numero', '$prod', '{$cantidad[$index]}', '{$precio_unitario[$index]}')";
    // Aquí ejecutas la consulta para insertar este producto
    $resultado_productos = $conexion->query($guardar_venta_producto);
}
```

La consulta para insertar productos debe ejecutarse dentro del ciclo, de lo contrario, solo va a tomar en cuenta el último producto, porque la `$guardar_venta_producto` se sobrescribe en cada iteración.

En teoría, ambas consultas no van devolver falso, a menos que estés haciendo algo mal, por ejemplo, incluir un apóstrofe (comilla simple) en el nombre de cliente, digamos: `O'Connell`, porque no estás escapando los datos.

Puedes ejecutar las consultas y guardar el resultado en variables para mostrar el código que tienes al final:

```
if ($resultado_venta && $resultado_productos) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Factura Creada!");
    window.location.href="registrar_venta.php";
    </script>';

} else {    
    echo "Error: {$conexion->error}";
}
```

Deberías validar los datos para evitar cualquier posible error:

- El cliente existe
- La fecha es correcta
- Existe la forma de pago
- Productos:

  - El código no está vacío y el producto existe
  - La cantidad es mayor que cero
  - El precio deberías tomarlo de la base de datos

Comment: Muchas gracias ! pero aún tengo el mismo problema en la base de datos , hice un registro con 3 productos,  tanto en la tabla compuesta como en la tabla de la factura, se guarda solo un registro.

Comment: @KAROLYULIETHPACHECORODRIGUE, actualiza la pregunta con tu código actual, incluyendo cómo ejecutas la consulta, por favor.

Comment: Listo !, espero sirva.

Comment: @KAROLYULIETHPACHECORODRIGUE, listo, actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! me has ayudado un montón!!!