# enviar datos de una tabla Html a una base de datos con PHP

Tags: php, html, html5, bootstrap

buenas trate de ser simple con el titulo pero la verdad es que entiendo como se envían los datos de una tabla con php a mi base de datos, solo que los datos que consulto para la tabla los hago con un ciclo while y al hacer eso pues es mas sencillo por la cantidad de datos que tiene que traer de la base de datos a la cual estoy con consultando pero al querer enviar estos datos ya modificados a la base de datos solo envía la primera fila y tiene lógica por como lo estoy manejando, el problema es que quiero enviar todas las filas ya modificadas y no solo una como en este caso, solo que no se si la forma en que lo estoy haciendo es la correcta o si existe otra forma de hacer esto:

```
<?php
//datos a actualziar
$id = $_POST['id'];
$producto = trim($_POST['producto']);
$ExistenciaSucursal = trim($_POST['ExistenciasSucursal']);
$PrecioSucursal = trim($_POST['PrecioSucursal']);
$Sucursal = $_POST['Sucursal'];

//actualizacion


    if (empty($PrecioSucursal)) {
        
     } else {
        echo "<script>function funcion(){alert('se han actualizado los datos correctamente');}</script>";
        $actualizar = "INSERT INTO `productos_sucursales` (`producto`, `existencia_sucursal`, `precio_sucursal`, `sucursal`) VALUES ('$producto', '$ExistenciaSucursal', '$PrecioSucursal', '$Sucursal')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$actualizar);
     }

?>

                        <form action="asignar_productos_sucursal.php" method="post">
                            <div class="card-body">
                            <input type="submit" name="cambiar" class="btn btn-primary position-realtive end-50" value="cambiar" >
                                <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Producto</th>
                                    <th>Familia</th>
                                    <th>Existencias</th>
                                    <th>Cantidad para Sucursal</th>
                                    <th>Sucursal</th>
                                    <th>Precio Por Sucursal</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php
                                include('my_function.php');
                                $currency = getCurrency();
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM catalogo ORDER BY codigo ASC";
                                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                                $i = 1;
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['codigo'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td> <input type='text' value=". $row['nombre'] . " name='producto' readonly></td>";
                                    echo "<td> <input type='text' value=". $row['departamento'] . " name='detalles' readonly></td>";
                                    echo "<td> <input type='text' value=". $row['existencia'] . " name='region' readonly></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input type='text' value='$cantidad' placeholder='0' name='ExistenciasSucursal' ></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input type='text' value='$precio' placeholder='$0' name='PrecioSucursal' ></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input type='text' value='$sucursal'  placeholder='' name='Sucursal' ></td>";
                                    echo "</tr> ";
                                }
                                echo " </tbody>";
                                echo " </table>";
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

ahora les explico como "funciona" primero hago consulta de mi base de datos "catalogo" después esos datos los llamo y los pongo en el ciclo while una vez que están ahí pues me muestra todos los datos que tengo pero les voy a complementar otros datos (Cantidad para Sucursal, Sucursal, Precio Por Sucursal) que estos datos serán agregados en input una ves que los campos están llenos quiero enviar toda esta información a otra base de datos "productos_sucursales" y que ahí me muestre todos los datos pero solo me envía la primera fila a lo cual pienso que esta bien pero no es lo que necesito, espero tengan una respuesta o otra forma de resolverlo

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/393264/54039), solo necesitas tratar todos los campos como arreglos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Tengo problemas de inserción de datos , por un formulario en forma de tabla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/393248/tengo-problemas-de-inserci%c3%b3n-de-datos-por-un-formulario-en-forma-de-tabla)

Comment: @Triby lo hice como planteas pero al guardarlo en la base de datos queda como Array, ¿no habrá una forma de pasar los datos sin que sea array?

Comment: @Adiel, en la respuesta que te sugerí está la forma de recorrer los datos con un ciclo `foreach`, revisa esa parte.

Comment: @Triby lo único que no logro entender son estas dos variables $index y $prod o esta parte `foreach($producto as $index => $prod){}` que funcion tiene index con $prod

Comment: @Adiel, lee la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) para aclarar esas dudas.